# Fail to import large file on Magento 2 from admin

Tags: magento2, import, products, csv, file

I succeeded importing a csv file size 319KB with 357 products.  But failed to import a csv file size 571KB with only 349 products.   Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Is there any error message shown? What do your PHP settings (upload_max_filesize, max_execution_time, etc.) look like?

Comment: I am running on Magento CE 2.1.9.  It seems the import products from admin only works once for small csv products file.  I set upload_max_filesize to 1024 MB and  max_execution_time to 1800 seconds in my WAMP php.ini file.  There is no error message when I tried to import the second products csv file.

Comment: Do you know how to use F12 Developer Tools to capture the network traffic? There may provide hints for the errors encountered.

Comment: Yes, and I follow the net->XHR of the firebug on firefox browser.  I saw there were no request.

Comment: For IE F12 Developer Tools, I saw there is a request URL /admin/admin/import/start from the NETWORK tab. But no new products created.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set upload_max_filesize = 4M from your php.ini then you can upload.

Comment: I am very sure it's not the upload_max_filesize = 4M  issue.  I set it to 1024M in my php.ini already.

Comment: It's an answer but incorrect, 4M is simply not enough